# BMP transparent color key not displaying correctly

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, splash-screen

I'm using a C++ class called [CSplash](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7658/CSplash-A-Splash-Window-Class) which is used to display a splash window in the center of the screen. It is designed to load only bitmap file types. It allows an RGB transparent color key to display the BMP with a transparent background.

---

I have a PNG image.

[image: Transparent PNG]

I opened this image in Photoshop and added a background color (50, 200, 25) as a transparent key.

[image: Image Green BG]

I then save this image as a bitmap file in my project.

[image]

I am left with a file: **PowerUp.bmp**

In my C++ code, I imported the class mentioned above and in `WM_NCCREATE` I have the following code:

```
CSplash splash = CSplash("PowerUp.bmp", RGB(50, 200, 25));
splash.WindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
splash.ShowSplash();
splash.DoLoop();
```

When I run my program, the splash image shows with a transparent background, but not as expected. The result has some of the transparent color left around the icons.

[image: Splash Result]

How can I fix this to make it look exactly like the transparent original PNG file?

Comment: In 2004 bmp-files with alpha-channel was non-standard format. Probably you are better to search for newer CSplash :) And btw, "RGB transparent color key" does not mean "alpha channel".

Comment: @KonstantinL Alright, thank you. and yea I have no idea what to label it as!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that you original png image has transparent parts (glasses borders are not strictly opaque but more like smoothly transitioning to transparent), which is a common case. So having absolutely green background with this image above it results in green being altered a bit around glasses border and other images. And it is no longe (50, 200, 25), it could be (51, 201, 25) and no longer removed by CSplash.

What you need to do is save you original PNG in transparent format where alpha channel is only 1 bit (0 or 1, transparent or opaque) - thus transitions will be lost, reopen it, and the do the green background trick again.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, must be anti-aliasing, I'll try it now

Comment: Yepppppppppppppppppppppppppp fixed it in Photoshop! Ty!